# xpath: extract data from a node using xpath

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

I want to extract only the sales rank (which in this case is 5)

> **Amazon Best Sellers Rank:**    ***#5*** in
>   Books (    See
>   Top 100 in Books )

From web page : [http://www.amazon.com/Mockingjay-Hunger-Games-Book-3/dp/0439023513/ref=tmm_hrd_title_0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0439023513)

So far I have gotten down to this, which selects "Amazon Best Sellers Rank:":

```
//li[@id='SalesRank']/b/text()
```

I am using PHP `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath`.

Comment: pls provide what you have tried so far.

Comment: this is what i have till now : //li[@id='SalesRank']/b/text()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pure XPath:

```
substring-before(normalize-space(/html/body//ul/li[@id="SalesRank"]/b[1]/following-sibling::text()[1])," ")
```

However, if your input is a bit messy you might get more reliable results by using XPath to grab the parent node's text, and then using a regex on the text to get the specific thing you want.

Demonstration of both methods using PHP with `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath`:

```php
// Method 1: XPath only
$xp_salesrank = 'substring-before(normalize-space(/html/body//li[@id="SalesRank"]/b[1]/following-sibling::text()[1])," ")';

// Method 2: XPath and Regex
$regex_ranktext = 'string(/html/body//li[@id="SalesRank"])';
$regex_salesrank = '/Best\s+Sellers\s+Rank:\s*(#\d+)\s+/ui';

// Test URLs
$urls = array(
    'http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0439023513',
    'http://www.amazon.com/Mockingjay-Final-Hunger-Games-ebook/dp/B003XF1XOQ/ref=tmm_kin_title_0?ie=UTF8&m=AG56TWVU5XWC2',
);

// Results
$ranks = array();
$ranks_regex = array();

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $d = new DOMDocument();
    $d->loadHTMLFile($url);
    $xp = new DOMXPath($d);

    // Method 1: use pure xpath
    $ranks[] = $xp->evaluate($xp_salesrank);

    // Method 2: use xpath to get a section of text, then regex for more specific item
    // This method is probably more forgiving of bad HTML.
    $rank_regex = '';
    $ranktext = $xp->evaluate($regex_ranktext);
    if ($ranktext) {
        if (preg_match($regex_salesrank, $ranktext, $matches)) {
            $rank_regex = $matches[1];
        }
    }
    $ranks_regex[] = $rank_regex;

}

assert($ranks===$ranks_regex); // Both methods should be the same.
var_dump($ranks);
var_dump($ranks_regex);
```

The output I get is:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "#4"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "#3"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "#4"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "#3"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Francis. however it is throwing following error:  PHP Warning:  DOMXPath::query() [<a href='domxpath.query'>domxpath.query</a>]: Invalid expression

Comment: Check your copy-pasting, because it clearly works. See new code.

Comment: Tried using the exact code but it fetches null for this page : http://www.amazon.com/Mockingjay-Final-Hunger-Games-ebook/dp/B003XF1XOQ/ref=tmm_kin_title_0?ie=UTF8&m=AG56TWVU5XWC2    (when it should actually fetch '3')

Comment: If you remove `ul/` it works on this page too. Amazon's html is pretty bad so it looks like different pages produce inconsistent DOMs in libxml2's html parser. Since you have a PHP host language it might be better to get the text value of the parent node and then get the actual number with a regex instead of doing it all in XPath.

Comment: removing ul/ did not help :(   the regex route : tried substr($homepage, strpos($homepage, 'Paid in Kindle Store'),-10);  but its bringing back the compltete html

Comment: Substr is not a regex...  I've updated the code above with both the urls you mentioned and the output I get. Clearly this works so I would investigate elsewhere than the XPath for the problem. Maybe there's a bug in your code or you're getting different html. You haven't actually showed us the *code* you are using, just the XPath, so perhaps you are using `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
substring-before(substring-after($expr, '#'), ' ')
```

**where `$expr` should be substituted by your expression**:

```
   substring-before(substring-after(//li[@id='SalesRank']/b, '#'), ' ')
```

Or, if the right expression that selects the text node is (as per @FrancisAvila):

```
/html/body//ul/li[@id="SalesRank"]/b[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

then the above becomes:

```
substring-before(
   substring-after(/html/body//ul/li[@id="SalesRank"]
                  /b[1]/following-sibling::text()[1], '#'), 
   ' ')
```

Comment: The text he desires is not a child of `//li[@id='SalesRank']/b` but a following-sibling.

Comment: @FrancisAvila: But he said otherwise... Nevermind, he just needs to substitute the right expression for `$expr`

Comment: does not work either way. fetches null  tried it on this page : http://www.amazon.com/Mockingjay-Final-Hunger-Games-ebook/dp/B003XF1XOQ/ref=tmm_kin_title_0?ie=UTF8&m=AG56TWVU5XWC2

Comment: @Abhi: If so, then you have misled the readers that `//li[@id='SalesRank']/b` selects the element, from whose string value you want to extract data. You must provide an example XML, so that any XPath expression could be verified.

Comment: apologies if i have confused you. I dont have an XML I am trying to extract the Sales Rank of a book from Amazon's site:  <b>Amazon Best Sellers Rank:</b>
#3 Paid in Kindle Store (
<a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/ref=pd_dp_ts_kstore_1">See Top 100 Paid in Kindle Store</a>    The issue is that the value that i want to extract is not part of any node... it is outside of the nodes. check the Sales rank sectio on this page http://www.amazon.com/Mockingjay-Final-Hunger-Games-ebook/dp/B003XF1XOQ/ref=tmm_kin_title_0?ie=UTF8&m=AG56TWVU5XWC2