# Getting required element from foreach loop

Tags: php, regex, arrays, xpath

i am using the following code to scrape some data from amazon

```
$nodelist = $xpath_cat->query('//li[@id="SalesRank"]/text()');
foreach ($nodelist as $node) {
$nodearr[] = trim($node->textContent);
}
var_dump($nodearr);
```

and dumping the result, the output is

```
array
 0 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => string '#14,000 Paid in Kindle Store (' (length=30)
  2 => string ')' (length=1)
  3 => string '' (length=0)
  4 => string '#21,322 Paid in Kindle Store (' (length=30)
  5 => string ')' (length=1)
  6 => string '' (length=0)
  7 => string '#20,957 Paid in Kindle Store (' (length=30)
  8 => string ')' (length=1)
```

what is want is on # part which is element 2 in array like

```
#"#20,957 Paid in Kindle Store"
```

how can modify the code to get my output? i was thinking it to use `unset()` but i am confused in implementing it. also, there is "(" which also needs to be deleted from the string

Guide me please..how can i modify my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To select only the wanted subset of the currently selected text nodes, use**:

```
//li[@id="SalesRank"]/text()[starts-with(., '#')]
```

You can select each individual such node using its 1-based index.

**For example**:

```
(//li[@id="SalesRank"]/text()[starts-with(., '#')])[3]
```

**selects this text node:**

```
#20,957 Paid in Kindle Store (
```

**To get the text without the trailing `"("` character, use the `translate()` (or `substring()`) function**:

```
   translate((//li[@id="SalesRank"]/text()[starts-with(., '#')])[3], 
             '(', 
             '')
```

when evaluated produces:

```
#20,957 Paid in Kindle Store
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be [answered pretty thoroughly here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922450/xpath-extract-data-from-a-node-using-xpath).

It looks like the accepted answer uses:

```
substring-before(normalize-space(/html/body//ul/li[@id="SalesRank"]/b[1]/following-sibling::text()[1])," ")
```

And also shows some other nice options.

Comment: sorry for mistake, i had opened that question a bit late and got the updated answer after posting this question..well...what i think ..should i use the update xpath?

Comment: I have no idea, but I'm as curious as you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just tweak your xpath query a little, but you could use also [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to filter the array. For example like this:

```
array_filter($data, function($e) {return $e[0] == "#";});
```

With an input of, for example

```
$data = array('#14,000 Paid in Kindle Store (', '', '(');
```

the above array_filter gives

```
array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(30) "#14,000 Paid in Kindle Store ("
}
```

You could then filter/transform the single values, for example using array_map:

```
array_map(function($e) {return rtrim($e, ' (');}, $data);
```

which would leave you with:

```
array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(28) "#14,000 Paid in Kindle Store"
}
```